# MySQL query with inner join fail

Tags: mysql

I am writing a php mysql application and I was running the following select query:

```
SELECT 
    individual_marriage.pk_marriage_ID, 
    husband.individual_person_FirstName, 
    husband.individual_person_LastName, 
    wife.individual_person_FirstName, 
    wife.individual_person_LastName 
FROM 
    (
        (
            individual_marriage AS im 
            INNER JOIN person AS husband ON 
            individual_marriage.fk_IndividualID_male=husband.pk_person
        ) 
        INNER JOIN person AS wife ON individual_marriage.fk_IndividualID_female=wife.pk_person
    ) 
WHERE 
    im.Sec5A_applicable='yes'
```

The problem lies somewhere in the WHERE statement and the mysqli_query returns false. mysql_errno() and mysql_error() is also returning blank somehow.

Comment: I dunno why the question has been marked down. I've tried a lot to solve it, tried several different syntax styles. And I can run it without the where statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  im.pk_marriage_ID, 
        husband.individual_person_FirstName, 
        husband.individual_person_LastName, 
        wife.individual_person_FirstName, 
        wife.individual_person_LastName 
FROM    individual_marriage AS im INNER JOIN person AS husband
                ON im.fk_IndividualID_male = husband.pk_person
        INNER JOIN person AS wife
                ON im.fk_IndividualID_female = wife.pk_person) 
WHERE   im.Sec5A_applicable = 'yes'
```

We can help more if you could post the `SCHEMA` of your table. If you run this query and return blank rows, *it means that there are columns in the `individual_marriage` that are not in the table `person`* and because you are also using **INNER JOIN**.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  im.pk_marriage_ID, 
        COALESCE(husband.individual_person_FirstName,'') as  husbandFirstName
        COALESCE(husband.individual_person_LastName, '') as  husbandFamilyName
        COALESCE(wife.individual_person_FirstName,'') as    WifeFirstName
        COALESCE(wife.individual_person_LastName ,'') as    WifeLastName
FROM    individual_marriage AS im LEFT JOIN person AS husband
                ON im.fk_IndividualID_male = husband.pk_person
        LEFT JOIN person AS wife
                ON im.fk_IndividualID_female = wife.pk_person) 
WHERE   im.Sec5A_applicable = 'yes'
```

Comment: Hi, deleting the parenthesis hasn't helped. The schema is like this. There is a person table, with pk_person as primary key. person table has males and females and their marriage is recorded in the individual_marriage table. Sec5A_applicable is a column in the individual_marriage table, with either yes or no.

Comment: If i just eliminate the entire where statement, i.e. /* WHERE im.Sec5A_applicable='yes' */, then the query works just fine. So the contention that the columns may not exist is wrong.

Comment: @ChinmayKamat i updated the answer. what is the data type of `Sec5A_applicable`?

Comment: Hello, it is enum('yes','no'). I'm trying the updated answer right now

Answer (score 0):

If you can attach CREATE table structure of both table indivisual_marriage and person table by executing this query:
SHOW CREATE TABLE `indivisual_marriage`;
SHOW CREATE TABLE `person`;

Also tell what you want to achieve using both tables may be we can frame a better query than this

Comment: CREATE TABLE `individual_marriage` (
 `pk_marriage_ID` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fk_IndividualID_male` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `fk_IndividualID_female` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `Date_Start` date NOT NULL,
 `Date_End` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `Sec5A_applicable` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pk_marriage_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: The Create Table result is too big to paste here. There are over 60 columns in that table. But the columns we are interested in are as follows: CREATE TABLE `person` (`pk_person` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `individual_person_FirstName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `individual_person_MiddleName` varchar(25) NOT NULL, `individual_person_LastName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,`individual_person_Gender` enum('male','female') NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`pk_person`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem out of sheer dumb luck. All I had to do was add a new set of parenthesis around the name of the first table in FROM clause. I'm reproducing the code here:

```
SELECT 
individual_marriage.pk_marriage_ID,  
husband.individual_person_FirstName, 
husband.individual_person_LastName, 
wife.individual_person_FirstName, 
wife.individual_person_LastName
FROM 
   (((individual_marriage) 
INNER JOIN
person AS husband
ON 
individual_marriage.fk_IndividualID_male=husband.pk_person) 
INNER JOIN
person AS wife
ON 
individual_marriage.fk_IndividualID_female=wife.pk_person) 
WHERE 
individual_marriage.Sec5A_applicable='yes'
```

This is something that is not making sense to me. I've not yet seen such a solution in any textbook so far. Can someone pls explain how the meaning of the statement changed after adding those parenthesis?